# why can't i delete this file on my pc?

Tags: windows-xp

I am trying [to install some software](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:IVbCoNfNnj4J:www.belshe.com/2007/12/06/how-to-install-lookout-on-outlook-2007/+getting+lookout+working+on+outlook+2007&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.com) and it requires removing the following file:

- cd  %SYSTEMROOT%\assembly\GAC
- rename  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Old

the problem is that when I do the rename, it looks like it's successful but it doesn't seem to actually delete  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

i tried to explicitly do:

```
 del Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
```

and again it looks like it works but then when i do a "dir" i still see that file.

Do you have any suggestions on why this wouldn't allow me to delete this file.  I have outlook closed when i am doing this so i wouldn't think outlook is locking the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) you could use sysinternals [ProcessMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what's using the file. Kill that, then delete the file.

2) You could also use the [RunOnceEx](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232509) registry key to have the file deleted on boot before you run anything that may use it. I don't have a windows box to create an example, maybe someone else can add to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Boot from a XP cd and get to the command prompt, delete it from there.

here is how to get to the command prompt from CD.

http://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=5097

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me I use Unlocker by Cedrick Collomb.

This little and hand utility always did the trick for me really easily: right click --> unlock & delete.

http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/

It is easier and more feature-packed than other suggested tools (check the "Similar programs and why Unlocker is better" table in the link above)